# Tab Bar not showing after pushing View Controller with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a TabBarController TBC with 5 tabs. In Tab 1, I have a NavigationController NVC with a root view controller called VC1. I then have segues to VC2 and VC3 from VC1 (depending on buttons pressed).

VC2 is on the same storyboard as VC1, but VC3 is on a different storyboard.

Problem:
When I transition to VC2 from VC1, the tab bar on the bottom shows up properly as it should, but when I transition to VC3 from VC1, it is a ghost tab bar that disappears whenever any new transition happens (essentially it does not show up/get updated, it only shows the remnants from VC1).

I suspect VC2 works because it is on the same storyboard as VC1 and there is a clear segue from VC1 to VC2. The storyboard shows VC2's safe area shrink, as it makes room for the tab bar.

This is not the case with VC3. Since it is on a different storyboard, I attached a reference to VC3 on VC1's storyboard and put a segue to that reference. This does not fix the problem, and the safe area of VC3 does not shrink.

I use the following code to transition from VC1 to VC2 AND from VC1 to VC3:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1or2") as? ViewController1or2
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

GIF of problem:

https://i.imgur.com/jdQY4BT.mp4

Comment: Include the gif with problem to your post, please.

Comment: Also, what is the point of segues if you make the transition from the code? Is the code that you showed us in VC1 class for both VC2 and VC3?

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov I have added the gif. Thanks!

Comment: @VladRusu The segues are for graphical presentation. And yes the code is for both transitions to VC2 and to VC3.

Comment: Ok, so segues will play no role here. I is weird that this happens. Do you handle the tap on the bottom buttons manually? Or do you make use of the `UITabBarController`'s delegate to set the view controllers? Maybe you are pushing on the wrong `navigationController`. I think we'll need more related code to find the issue.

Comment: @VladRusu I do not handle the tap on the tab bar manually. I just double checked and am certain I'm using the right navigation view controller because the flow works, its just a UI issue. Also, I think the segues are the main issue. The only difference between VC2 (not shown in gif) and VC3 is that VC3 doesn't have an explicit segue (only a segue to VC3's reference)

Comment: Indeed, it could be the segues if they get triggered and you also perform the push manually. Which is the method that the mention code is in?

Comment: @VladRusu VC2's transition code is in a button press method. VC3's transition code is in a tableview's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Can you remove segues from Storyboard and see if problem persists or not, please?

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov I took out the segues and the same situation is present. VC2 works and VC3 does not work. I guess the problem is not segues. If you guys need, I can show another gif of VC2 working properly

Comment: any solution for this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: @LittlePeculiar it was a problem about not having the tab bar in the view controller on the storyboard if I remember correctly